# How to do pagination dynamically in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

i'm so new to jasper reporting,

What i'm trying to do is, i want to fetch 1000 records per page, so for this i'm using Jaspersoft Studio and used break element in the detail band by providing the Print When Expression as $V{PAGE_COUNT} == 1000 and also i have streched the page height to some point where it can take 1000 records. So till here everything is fine, but the problem is if im getting total 1200 in records then it is diplaying 1000 records for first page but in second page only 200 records by leaving 800 rows of empty space which is not accepted by client. All i want is that if second page is having only 200 rows the footer should be adjusted dynamically by eliminating those empty spaces.

Adding corresponding .jrxml code. So anyone's help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.9.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.9.0-cb8f9004be492ccc537180b49c026951f4220bf3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="BluePrint" pageWidth="1050" pageHeight="58270" columnWidth="1010" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="554b0f60-56e2-48fb-ab4b-782b23ffc73e">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter(ATT Dev DS)"/>
    <parameter name="Manufacturer" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select id, inserted, manufacturer, model, model_id, supported_protocols, os
from DEVICE_MODEL_CONFIG dm 
WHERE DM.MANUFACTURER = $P{Manufacturer}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ID"/>
    </field>
    <field name="INSERTED" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="INSERTED"/>
    </field>
    <field name="MANUFACTURER" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="MANUFACTURER"/>
    </field>
    <field name="MODEL" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="MODEL"/>
    </field>
    <field name="MODEL_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="MODEL_ID"/>
    </field>
    <field name="SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS"/>
    </field>
    <field name="OS" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="OS"/>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="151" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-20" width="1050" height="149" backcolor="#006699" uuid="f7182fe6-ad8d-458d-87db-0a9956733132"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="19" y="10" width="580" height="49" uuid="55c262d1-3e27-41ae-b5aa-621651bb240d"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="35" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[DeviceModelByManufacturer]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="154" y="100" width="200" height="30" uuid="c6f91dac-00d6-4417-a74d-3ed27f2048b6">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                        <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Manufacturer}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="23" y="72" width="191" height="31" uuid="bfab0c72-c839-4df0-9c3a-b782435f0d2e"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Input Param ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="23" y="99" width="170" height="31" uuid="be513fae-b3de-4249-824f-56d88e497340">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Manufacturer  : ]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="60" y="-13" width="79" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="cec167d1-338c-4327-87c9-e8d562b6af56">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d86176ec-d84b-4b93-997a-12ec39fe2bba"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="138" y="-13" width="142" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="129979bf-50e6-469b-a3d0-b483b6c4c820">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d18cc433-4eec-4e98-ac63-47f15c20b391"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Inserted]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="279" y="-13" width="165" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="4254e855-c30f-44af-9e1a-f929f5a94c34">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="c6fdfe7b-19cd-4a5d-8abf-681171d2a719"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Manufacturer]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="444" y="-13" width="153" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="546ecc90-d4de-4a67-9aa1-2d7dc2b1f14f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9c039bc5-f66e-467f-a303-907704885c37"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Model]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="597" y="-13" width="111" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="3d7452f4-781b-40b9-b017-7c510c384e7b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="322b6c0e-2f6f-409c-8490-d2bfa3840131"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Model Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="708" y="-13" width="222" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="a411dcd5-1d42-466c-aa61-7949935b30e7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d36b4bc1-f360-41bf-a258-224ca24b54a8"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Supported Protocols]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="930" y="-13" width="79" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="ed920403-94d5-422f-b160-dcdba73818cb">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="35c8a329-7e87-4a6b-9638-4a14ddbdb9d3"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[OS]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="-13" width="68" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="07abb5e5-c908-42c5-b176-3745a8faf239">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[S.No]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="15" width="1049" height="1" uuid="ad3f5b06-8577-4845-849e-5fa41c9656d0"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="46" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="56" y="0" width="85" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3aa7739c-b282-4652-9212-0ecafd9802ae">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d86176ec-d84b-4b93-997a-12ec39fe2bba"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="127" y="0" width="165" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3c274351-85b8-4230-9f5c-93d3a16607d0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d18cc433-4eec-4e98-ac63-47f15c20b391"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INSERTED}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="319" y="0" width="85" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="612397ed-b5a3-4814-acca-eb02637aa6b6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="c6fdfe7b-19cd-4a5d-8abf-681171d2a719"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MANUFACTURER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="450" y="0" width="140" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="48a7fd37-5c3c-4128-be55-524b1faeba9f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9c039bc5-f66e-467f-a303-907704885c37"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MODEL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="610" y="0" width="85" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="bc93a0f7-029a-46e8-833e-f1d93a0e5ae5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="322b6c0e-2f6f-409c-8490-d2bfa3840131"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MODEL_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="754" y="0" width="130" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b491681d-9911-4cae-a732-329cc896ec22">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d36b4bc1-f360-41bf-a258-224ca24b54a8"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="926" y="0" width="85" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f14acd18-e4cd-43d7-b71d-2efe2d57465a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="35c8a329-7e87-4a6b-9638-4a14ddbdb9d3"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7b247d2e-2508-4a1a-aee0-4f8fb2ff6b42">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="38" width="1009" height="1" uuid="2cd74f4c-6d2b-4ef3-ace7-2df7324cf744">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="45" width="1009" height="1" uuid="c1f9029e-7aa0-403f-98da-77622d32c71c">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_COUNT}==1000]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="41" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="10" width="1011" height="31" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="c32c84ba-d6bc-45dc-84c4-75e0fff85d64"/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="18" y="15" width="200" height="20" uuid="47dfcb65-3b96-4833-a285-1e0a8d16994d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="896" y="16" width="61" height="20" uuid="d7711d81-044c-49d5-be32-ee801032bfdb">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="957" y="16" width="40" height="20" uuid="f9512ca9-368f-4888-bdad-419fbb28f9a4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" of " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**Nasir**

Comment: Please share the relevant jrxml file

Comment: Hi @Lakshan i have updated the .jrxml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to get the solution for this, as i have done the below,

1. Place the footer in the column footer band instead Page footer band.
2. set the below property,

`<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" .... isFloatColumnFooter="true" ...>`

Answer (score 1):

try with this,

set the "Remove Line When Blank" property of the text field to true

```
isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"
```

in the jrxml file,

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7b247d2e-2508-4a1a-aee0-4f8fb2ff6b42">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

set the "Float Column Footer" property of the report to true

```
isFloatColumnFooter="true"
```

in the jrxml file,

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" ..... isFloatColumnFooter="true" ...>
```

set the suitable condition for "Filter Expression" property of the report

example,

```
<filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}>0]]></filterExpression>
```

Comment: Hi @Lakshan, i have tried the solution you have provided but it doesn't made any difference as i'm still getting the empty rows...

Comment: please set the above property for all text fields

Comment: yes i have set the value to true for all the text fields...i will update the .jrxml file here again, pls have a look and let me know where i'm doing wrong

Comment: i have tried changing the position type to Float for all components in the page footer, but it didn't worked, above i have updated the relevant .jrxml

Comment: sorry for the mistake, please refer the above edited answer

Comment: Hi Lakshan, i tried your suggestion but didn't worked as im still getting the empty rows, pls find the updated .jrxml code

Comment: Hi @Lakshan, i also had tried setting all components of page footer to float and Float Column Footer property to true which is not helping, not sure why its not working for me when its working for you ?...please do provide your suggestion

Comment: sorry for the late response, please refer the above updated answer

Comment: Hi Lakshan, i was able make this working please see my answer, thank you that you have taken out some time for replying